# Set Initial Data for Kendo DataSource

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a page which uses a Kendo Grid attached to a Kendo DataSource which pulls data from the server. When the page initially loads another request is done by the datasource to pull data. This causes a delay in the page actually loading. What I would like to do is send the initial data model in the page response but I cannot find a what to push that data into the DataSource. Has anyone else tried doing this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass json data in your page first call.
2. Your pass json is set into model.
3. Set your json into data.

EX.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ]
});
```

Set datasource of grid.

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.setDataSource(dataSource);
```